# Correctly using loop.create_future

Tags: python, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I was reading the Python documentation and [PyMotW](https://pymotw.com/3/index.html) book trying to learn Async/Await, Futures, and Tasks.

[Coroutines and Tasks documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines):

> Normally there is no need to create Future objects at the application
>   level code.

From the [future documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#creating-futures-and-tasks) it states the following:

> loop.create_future()
>
> Create an asyncio.Future object attached to the event loop.
>
> This is the preferred way to create Futures in asyncio. This lets third-party event loops provide alternative implementations of the
>   Future object (with better performance or instrumentation).

However, in [PyMotW chapter on Future](https://pymotw.com/3/asyncio/futures.html#waiting-for-a-future), the author creates a `future` object like this:

```
all_done = asyncio.Future()
```

I assume because the book is slightly behind the current version of Python. To correct this, I did the following:

```
future_Obj = event_loop.create_future()
```

So the authors full code becomes:

```
import asyncio


def mark_done(future, result):
    print('setting future result to {!r}'.format(result))
    future.set_result(result)


event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:

    future_Obj = event_loop.create_future()
    print('scheduling mark_done')
    event_loop.call_soon(mark_done, future_Obj, 'the result')

    print('entering event loop')
    result = event_loop.run_until_complete(future_Obj)
    print('returned result: {!r}'.format(result))
finally:
    print('closing event loop')
    event_loop.close()

print('future result: {!r}'.format(future_Obj.result()))
```

**Question:**

Is `future_Obj = event_loop.create_future()` in the sample above, the correct way to create a `future` object according to the documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is `future_Obj = event_loop.create_future()` in the sample above, the correct way to create a future object according to the documentation?

Yes, in the code as shown, that is exactly the way to do it.

One thing to watch out for is that a future is tied to an event loop, so creating a future at top-level creates a future tied to the loop that `asyncio.get_event_loop()` returns initially. Once you switch to [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run), you will get an error because each invocation of `asyncio.run` creates a new event loop.

To avoid that issue, a top-level future can start off as `None` and be created inside a coroutine, using `global` as appropriate. And since you're passing the future explicitly (which is a good practice to follow), you don't need a global variable at all:

```
def mark_done(future, result):
    print('setting future result to {!r}'.format(result))
    future.set_result(result)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = loop.create_future()
    print('scheduling mark_done')
    loop.call_soon(mark_done, future, 'the result')
    print('suspending the coroutine')
    result = await future
    print('awaited result: {!r}'.format(result))
    print('future result: {!r}'.format(future.result()))
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('entering the event loop')
    result = asyncio.run(main())
    print('returned result: {!r}'.format(result))
```

Note that when using `asyncio.run`, you never need to explicitly close the loop, that is done automatically. If you are using Python 3.6 or earlier, you can replace `asyncio.run(main())` with `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity before Python 3.7, was the way to create a future object done like this, `all_done = asyncio.Future()`? The author runs a bug tracker, so we could tell him that line has changed in Python 3.7.

Comment: The `create_future` event loop method was introduced in Python 3.5.2, so it's not a 3.7 novelty. A more serious issue with the guide is that creating and manipulating raw futures is considered bad style in modern async programming. Practically all examples that use `x.add_done_callback(foo)` would benefit from being expressed as coroutines that await `x` and then do `foo`.

Comment: Should I just abandon that guide/book as a learning resource? If so, what other resources are there to learn async/await, tasks, and futures?

Comment: @EmilyScott I wouldn't go that far, it's not *that* bad. As for other resources, [here](https://morestina.net/blog/1213/asyncio-reading-list) is a reading list that I compiled when I was studying asyncio. Perhaps it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, I bookmarked it :D. You even have PyMotW under the intermediate section.

Comment: I asked a more detailed [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54282226/trying-to-undestand-why-creating-and-manipulating-futures-a-bad-practice?noredirect=1&lq=1) about why creating and using futures are bad practice, could you help? It was based on your answer to my question above.